# Hide critical messages when testing PyQt

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, pyqt4

I have a GUI, which works well, under any circumstances. No error, no critical messages.
I want to test some elements, so I wrote the code:

import unittest
import logging
import sys
from PyQt4.QtTest import QTest
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from gui import MainWindow

```
class TestMainWindow(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication([])
        # this is for disabling messages from logger
        logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)

    def test_only_first_checked(self):
        self.ui = MainWindow()
        self.assertEqual(self.ui.first_radio.isChecked(), True)
        self.assertEqual(self.ui.second_radio.isChecked(), False)
        self.assertEqual(self.ui.third_radio.isChecked(), False)

    def test_bottom_radios_disabled(self):
        self.ui = MainWindow()
        self.assertEqual(self.ui.left_radio.isEnabled(), False)
        self.assertEqual(self.ui.right_radio.isEnabled(), False)
```

And the output is - a lot of lines like:

> (python3:12405): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion
>   'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
>
> (python3:12405): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion
>   'GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed
>
> (python3:12405): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion
>   'GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed

and then

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.546s
OK
```

I've never gotten any of this error messages when running GUI, so I'm wondering If it's possible to disable/hide them.

Comment: Why are you binding the `MainWindow` instance to the `TestCase` instance in the test methods? That's not necessary and a possible source of errors if you forget that line in a test and then ”silently” reuse an instance from an earlier test. Maybe you want to move that line from the tests into the `setUp()` method‽

Comment: @BlackJack I tried moving ```self.ui = MainWindow()``` to ```setUp()``` method but anyway was getting critical messages. Only my answer fixed this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the messages, it's simply ”wrong” the way you do it. Because of the potential problem I've described. I'm also a bit puzzled why you get Gtk error messages from a Qt GUI‽

Answer (score 0):

Added to **TestMainWindow**

```
def tearDown(self):
    self.app.deleteLater()
```

and now it doesn't show any critical message.